# What does this icon in the margin of the text editor mean?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

There is an icon in the margin of the text editor that has an up arrow and a "I" with a blue background. What does this mean?

I am using VS2019 16.10.0. and it is .netfx Winform project.

[image: icon in margin]

Comment: I would assume, that this means `FmMain` inherits from `Form`. Have you tried to click on it? In IntelliJ-based IDEs there is a similiar thing and when you click on it, it will lead you to the class you inherit from (`Form` in this case)

Comment: @leun4m Nothing happen when I clicked it, maybe you're right.

Comment: Never seen this icon before. It's maybe coming from some VS extension.

Comment: BTW those icons are called "margin glyphs". You may try to google that term for more info, but the chances to find this particular margin glyph are very small.

Comment: Thank you, this icon appears after upgraded VS to 16.10.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This icon shows the inheritance chain/margin and was added in version 16.10 of Visual Studio.  From the [16.10 release notes for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes-v16.10#NETProductivity):

> There is now a visual representation for navigating and inspecting the inheritance chain. This option is off by default so you will need to turn it on in Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced and select Show inheritance margin. Enabling inheritance margin will add new icons to the margins representing your code’s implementations and overrides. Clicking on the inheritance margin icon will display inheritance options that you can select to navigate to.
> [image]

Sure enough, if you navigate to the option in the tools menu, it is at the bottom:

[image: inheritance margin option]

I would check your settings for this - it should be off by default, meaning *somehow* it was turned on for you.  The icon should show the inheritance chain if you click on it.  If it isn't, perhaps turn the option off and back on, or restart Visual Studio (it's experimental apparently, so it could be bugged).

Comment: Thank you, yes it is, I reported my [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/53708).

Comment: It is not checked by default, it by me, but I don't know this option related to this icon at that time.